# Eigenvalue Problem in dynamical systems with complex variables

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Sorry if my question seem too obvious :

If "$X$" is a complex vector and "$\bar X$" its complex conjugate, then  how to find the eigenvalues of the following problem:

$\dfrac{dX}{dt} = AX + B \bar X$    (eq. 1)

In a first attempt I tried considering the conjugate of eq.1 so to form a complete system. It seemed to work, although I was told this procedure is wrong. 
If ayone could help, I would be glad to be referred to a book on mathematics or something.

Thank you and best regards

Comment: I edited your question to make $\LaTeX$ work, and I also replaced your "diff(X, t)" with $\frac{dX}{dt}$; hope I got the semantics right!  If not, you can change it back if you want.  Cheers!